# Stumped on aligning elements within Bootstrap 3 Nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Thanks for checking out my post. First time reaching out for help.

My problem is I can't seem to center the elements within my nav no matter what I try.

Here's what my code is putting out.

[image: Here's what my code is putting out.]

Here's what I'd like it to do.

[image: Here's what I'd like it to do.]

So basically, I'd like to center the content in the middle `col-sm-8` & the `col-sm-2` on the right side of the page as well.

Here's my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Javascript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- My CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

<title>Working Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- The Navbar & row-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse row">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- The logo Img. -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 L-sm-2">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Img/logo.jpg" style=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Begin Page Links. This can change the text size also. -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-sm-8 PageLinks">

            <!-- Play! -->
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Play! <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">PvE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">PvP</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- About -->
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">The Game</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Monster Manual</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- Forum -->
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>

            <!-- Statistics -->
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Statistics <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">PvE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">PvP</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- Armory -->
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Armory <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">PC Armory</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">PC Builder</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>               

            <!-- Help! -->
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Help <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>               
        </ul>


        <!-- The sign up / sign in stuff. -->
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right R-sm-2 col-sm-2">
            <ul class="">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's my CSS

```
* {
/* Makes sure that the padding and border are included in the total width and height of the elements in the Grid. */
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Setting the heignt for the logo in the nav bar. */
nav a img {
max-height: 100px;
width: auto;
}

/* Setting the height for the columns in the nav. */
nav .col-sm-2, .col-sm-8{
height: 140px;
}

/* Setting the navbar height & the opacity */
.navbar{
height: 140px;
opacity: .9;
}

/* Setting the left border for the Sign up / Sign in area. */
.R-sm-2{
border-left: 2px solid white;
line-height: 3.3;
}

/* Setting the left border for the Sign up / Sign in area. */
.L-sm-2{
border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.PageLinks{

}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I would change your nav tag to a div tag like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
```

Answer (score 0):

[I found the solution myself using Flexbox. I'm posting it here for anyone who might find this in the future with the same problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp0S0.png)

All I did was add this to my CSS above.

```
.PageLinks{
/* Makes the text larger */
font-size: 2.7em;
/* Sets the container to flex */
display: flex;
/* Centers the content horizontally */
justify-content: center;
/* Centers the content vertically */
align-items: center;
}
```